# Missing namespace or type for ICommand

Tags: c#, icommand

Microsoft Visual Studio can't compile my code because the namespace for ICommand is missing. But it is System.Windows.Input, isn't it?

```
using System.Windows.Input;

internal class CommandCreate : ICommand
{
   //code
}
```

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have created a WPF Application. ICommand is part of `System.Windows.Input` namespace and the `System.dll` Assembly.

#### More Information

- [MSDN - ICommand Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx)